# what is the best way to implement operation-wise and row-wise authentication if there is something like this

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm creating a project using DRF (Django Rest Framework), I'm stuck at a point while updating data in tables, I find it highly vulnerable to misuse. My code is below

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from Mera.settings.common import AUTH_USER_MODEL
from Mera.constant import UNIT_TYPES


class Item(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='item_owner', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    previous_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="")
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="")
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from commodity.models import Item
from Mera.settings.common import AUTH_USER_MODEL


class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Item.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        response = super().to_representation(instance)
        response['owner'] = UserSerializer(instance.owner).data
        return response

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Item.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = AUTH_USER_MODEL
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'items']
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import mixins
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from commodity.models import Item
from commodity.serializers import ItemSerializer, UserSerializer

class ItemList(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                  generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

class ItemDetail(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                    generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Doubt i have is that if someone gets API method and data-format from dev-tools and using its own authentication, he/she will be able to **change(UPDATE)** data of any row just by changing the **id (Primary Key)** in the request, this way they can change the data of the whole table even if they have the role to do it or not.

Also, similarly, if someone removes **id (Primary Key)** from the request, instance.save() might create a new row, even from the update API.

Please DRF, Django community guide me if I'm wrong, provide me with the best way to implement operation-wise and row-wise authentication if there is something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable creation of objects, do not inherit from `mixins.CreateModelMixin`

If you want to make objects editable and viewable by their owners only, create a permission class, and add it to the viewset's `permission_classes`

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsOwnerPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.owner == request.user

class ItemDetail(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                    generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes [IsOwnerPermission]
```

If you want to disable creation of objects, do not inherit from `mixins.CreateModelMixin`

Sources:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createmodelmixin